# Python3 unbound error. How can i fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

I am receiving the unbloud error when trying to test a python script at the command line. The script was written to connect to an ssh server and pull real time data(temperatuures from. After critical low or high temps, it is supposed to start an automatic shutdown. Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Code is below" server details were deleted for security";

```
import paramiko
import time

def get_temperature():
# Simulate fetching temperature data from the server
# Replace this with actual code to fetch real-time temperature data
# For example, using SSH to run a command that retrieves the temperature
return 25  # Replace with the actual temperature value

def main():
# SSH server details
ssh_host = 'your_server_ip'
ssh_port = 22
ssh_username = 'your_username'
ssh_password = 'your_password'

# Connect to the SSH server
try:
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(ssh_host, ssh_port, ssh_username, ssh_password)
    print("Connected to the SSH server.")
   
    # Fetch temperature data
    temperature = get_temperature()
    print(f"Current temperature: {temperature}°C")

    # Check temperature conditions and perform actions
    if temperature >= 35:
        print("Temperature is too high. Initiating PDU shutdown.")
        # Implement PDU shutdown command here
       
    elif temperature <= 13:
        print("Temperature is too low. Initiating PDU shutdown.")
        # Implement PDU shutdown command here

    else:
        print("Temperature is within acceptable range.")
   
 except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
   
 finally:
    if ssh_client:
        ssh_client.close()
        print("Disconnected from the SSH server.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Error below also the temperature is incorrect so I know it is not connecting:
CPU Temperature: 44.0 °C
CPU Temperature: 44.0 °C
An error occurred: module 'paramiko' has no attribute 'SSHClient'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "paramikochico", line 44, in 
main()
File "paramikochico", line 39, in main
if ssh_client:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ssh_client' referenced before assignment

Comment: Can you verify that what we see as indentation is what your code is? It looks like it is off by a tab in general.

Comment: yes sorry but that is the code

Comment: My best guess is that you have a folder `paramiko` or file named `paramiko.py` in your project that is overriding this library. After that, the code in general looks to be off one tab. For example, in the final two lines of code (as I see them) your `main()` needs to be tabbed to the right four spaces.